# TeX Live doesn't install pdflatex and texworks

Tags: pdftex, texlive, installing, texworks

After system crash I was trying to reinstall TeXLive on Windows 8.1 at home and at the same time on another computer at work with Windows 10. I was following the instructions from [tug.org/texlive](https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html) and used the file `install-tl-windows.exe' but contrary to what is claimed there, neither TeXWorks nor pdflatex were installed. I saved the log shown during install and the pdflatex is not even mentioned as an attempt during the process. I thought the issue might be the remains of the previous TeXLive on Windows 8. But the situation with the other PC (with no LateX previously installed) shows the contrary. What am I missing?
Is there any other source from which I could download a complete install? Last time when I did that was 8 years ago and I remember having some issues, too. Unfortunately, I cannot recall how I sorted it out then.
TeXLive submenu to the Windows start menu also doesen't get added. There may be some other files missing, too, about which I don't know. I noticed missing TeXWorks, which I installed separately, but I cannot add the correct folder to the path, as there is no folder containing pdflatex. The files with extension '.tex' are recognised and open in TeXWorks but obviously, the code is not executed and 'not properly configured' message is displayed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE!

Comment: Even if something went wrong during install, you should have a graphical tool to manage the installation (TeX Live Manager). Did you try adding packages with it?

Comment: I searched my HD for the phrase 'TeXLive manager' and nothing was found